# Deploy Rest based angular2 app Ask

Tags: apache-2.2

I had previously asked this question on stackoverflow , but was asked to try my luck on this forum . So here is my question.

I have developed a web application which is composed of 2 seperate projects.

The front end application is a angular2 project running on node js server on local computer.

The rest based backend is java spring application . This running on apache tomcat on local computer .Both the apps can exchange data between them and they work fine.

I can host my Java spring application on apache tomcat but where do I host my angular2 frontend project so that I can make rest based ajax calls to my backend server.

Can you suggest some free and easy way to host this angular2 frontend project so that . I have done some research on Heroku , OpenShift , AWS and Firebase . This has left me utterly confused .

For example if I choose heroku I need to upload my code to public repo which is not possible for me. Firebase looked like a wise choice until I read that they donot allow rest call to other servers.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no dynamic content of any kind, I would personally start with serving it directly out of AWS S3 with CloudFront CDN.

Comment: There is dynamic content in this application .

Comment: @IndronilChaudhuri I just mean in terms of the HTML, JS, and CSS.  Is that static at the time it's first delivered to the client, and then any dynamism is done with AJAX?  If so then S3 is fine. Otherwise you'll need something else.

Comment: That is exactly the case . When it is first delivered to the client , HTML , CSS and JS are all static. The dynamism comes in through requests to a different server which has some exposed REST based endpoints and this happens through the mechanism of AJAX . So I suppose I will opt for S3. Thank you so much for clarifying my confusion.